# How do you do a power in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How do I do this question in Matlab:

4^3^2

Should the answer be 4069

Comment: See my Saturn Fiddle: https://saturnapi.com/fullstack/power-chain

Comment: In MATLAB (contrary to most other languages I know), the power operator is left-associative, which means that `4^3^2` means `(4^3)^2`. See http://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/_power.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are doing homework. Let's walk through the way to do this.

What does `4^3^2` mean, exactly?

Well, `4^3` means `4` raised to the 3rd power, or `4*4*4`.

Then we need to raise that to the 2nd power (`^2`).

```
4^3 = 4 x 4 x 4 = 16 x 4 = 64

4^3^2 = 64^2 = 64 x 64 = 4096
```

The simplest way to do this in MATLAB would be to type exactly `4^3^2` in the command line.

To check the answer MATLAB gives you, you should perform the calculation in a different way using a calculator. This allows you to ensure that not only is your answer correct, but that you understand the arithmetic behind it.